# My thymeleaf template isn't displaying information in a table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm working on creating a view, using a thymeleaf template, that uses a dropdown list to select an employee from a MariaDB database and then the selected employees details are supposed to display in a table. The dropdown list is rendering correctly and I'm able to select an employee from the database but the table isn't displaying any information for the selected employee. I've inspected the HTML elements and inspected the networks page and everything is working correctly and should be displaying as expected.

**This is the code for my HTML page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--Set the Content Security Policy to restrict sources and styling-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src 'self';
    style-src 'self' 'sha256-4KSAL7ZM2P2drg9CSrxTq8z0SUKLRcHA5YsAnaqOpGE=';">

    <!-- Set the title of the html page -->
    <title>Employee View</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Internal stylesheet for styling the HTML document -->
<style integrity="sha256-4KSAL7ZM2P2drg9CSrxTq8z0SUKLRcHA5YsAnaqOpGE=">
    body {
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        background-color: #00212f;
        margin: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h2 {
        color: #ffffff;
        border: #dddddd;
    }

    form {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    label {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 10px;
        color: #dddddd;
    }

    select {
        padding: 5px;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    th, td {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    th {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    li {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    p {
        color: #dddddd;
        align-content: center;
    }
</style>

<!-- Heading for the employee view section -->
<h2> Employee view </h2>
<!-- Form/dropdown list for selecting an employee -->
<form method="get">
    <label for="selectEmployee">Select Employee:</label>
    <select id="selectEmployee" name="employeeId" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select an employee</option>
        <!-- Populate the dropdown with employees -->
        <option th:if="${employees != null}" th:each="employee : ${employees}" th:value="${employee.employee_id}" th:text="${employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName}"></option>
    </select>
</form>

<!-- Table for displaying employee details -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <th>Last Name:</th>
        <th>Email:</th>
        <th>Hire date:</th>
        <th>Department:</th>
        <th>Position:</th>
        <th>Onboarding tasks:</th>
    </tr>

**This is the section that isn't working correctly:**
    <!-- Check that an employee has been selected from the dropdown -->
    <tr th:if="${selectEmployee != null}">
        <!-- Display details for the selected employee -->
        <td th:text="${selectEmployee.firstName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${selectEmployee.lastName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${selectEmployee.email}"></td>
        <td th:text="${selectEmployee.hireDate}"></td>
        <td th:text="${selectEmployee.department}"></td>
        <td th:text="${selectEmployee.position}"></td>

        <td>
            <ul>
                <!-- Iterate over the tasks for the selected employee -->
                <li th:each="task : ${selectEmployee.tasks}">
                    <span th:text="${task.taskName}"></span> -
                    <span th:text="${task.description}"></span> -
                    <span th:text="${task.dueDate}"></span> -
                    <span th:text="${task.assignedTo}"></span> -
                    <span th:text="${task.completed} ? 'Completed' : 'Pending'"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- Display an error message if no employees are available -->
<p th:if="${employees == null || #lists.isEmpty(employees)}">No employees available to display.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is the related code in my controller:**

```
  @GetMapping("/employees")
    public String getEmployeeView(Model model) {
        // Retrieve the list of all employee details from the EmployeeService class.
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmployeeDetails();
        // Add the list of employee details to the model.
        log.info("Retrieved employees: " + employees);
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        // Return and render the view.
        return "ViewEmployee";
    }
}
```

**This is my code in the repository for my project:**

```
public List<Employee> viewEmployeeDetails() {

        try {
            // SQL query to retrieve employee details along with onboarding tasks.
            String sql = "SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.email, e.hire_date, e.department, e.position, " +
                    "t.task_name, t.description, t.due_date, t.assigned_to, t.completed " +
                    "FROM employees e " +
                    "LEFT JOIN employees_tasks et ON e.employee_id = et.employee_id " +
                    "LEFT JOIN tasks t ON et.task_id = t.task_id";

            // Execute the SQL query and return a jdbcTemplate.
            return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (rs, rowNum) -> {
                // Create a new Employee object to store the retrieved details.
                Employee employee = new Employee();

                // Set basic employee details.
                employee.setId(rs.getInt("employee_id"));
                employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                employee.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                employee.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                employee.setHireDate(rs.getDate("hire_date").toLocalDate());
                employee.setDepartment(rs.getString("department"));
                employee.setPosition(rs.getString("position"));

                // Create a Task object to onboarding task details.
                Task taskView = new Task();
                taskView.setTaskName(rs.getString("task_name"));
                taskView.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                taskView.setDueDate(rs.getDate("due_date").toLocalDate());
                taskView.setAssignedTo(rs.getInt("assigned_to"));
                taskView.setCompleted(rs.getBoolean("completed"));

                // Add the Task object to the employee's task list.
                employee.getTasks().add(taskView);
                // Return the Employee object with the associated onboarding tasks.
                return employee;
            });

        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            // Log and handle any exceptions related to accessing the database.
            log.severe("Error accessing the database");
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to access and retrieve employee details.", e);
        } catch (Exception e){
            // Log and handle general exceptions.
            log.severe("An error has occurred");
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("An error has occurred, please refresh the page or try again later.", e);
        }
        }
    }
```